# Understanding the behaviour of inject used with a lambda in Ruby

Tags: ruby, lambda, inject

I often plug pre-configured lambdas into enumerable methods like 'map', 'select' etc.
but the behavior of 'inject' seems to be different.
e.g. with

```
mult4 = lambda {|item| item * 4 }
```

then

```
(5..10).map &mult4
```

gives me

```
[20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40]
```

However, if I make a 2-parameter lambda for use with an inject like so,

```
multL = lambda {|product, n| product * n }
```

I want to be able to say

```
(5..10).inject(2) &multL
```

since 'inject' has an optional *single* parameter for the initial value,
but that gives me ...

```
irb(main):027:0> (5..10).inject(2) &multL
LocalJumpError: no block given
        from (irb):27:in `inject'
        from (irb):27
```

However, if I stuff the '&multL' into a *second* parameter to inject, then it works.

```
irb(main):028:0> (5..10).inject(2, &multL)
=> 302400
```

My question is "why does that work and not the previous attempt?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So the reason that

```
(5..10).map &mult4
```

works and

```
(5..10).inject(2) &multL
```

doesn't is that ruby parens are implicit in the first case, so it really means

```
(5..10).map(&mult4)
```

if you wanted, for the second case you could use

```
(5..10).inject 2, &multL
```

The outside the parens trick only works for passing blocks to a method, not lambda objects.