# Why can't I pass a block variable to inject?

Tags: ruby

Given,

```
  def wrapper &block
    (1..5).inject yield
  end

  proc = Proc.new {|sum, n| sum + n }
```

Why can't I do this call?

```
  wrapper &proc
  => NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

When looking inside, I see that inject has not been able to assign the memo or the obj, as rewriting the proc to be `proc = Proc.new {|memo, obj| puts memo ; puts obj }` returns 10 iterations of nothing. I also noted that `(1..5).inject` takes only one argument, what it passes in as the initial memo, and that technically it doesn't the block as a real argument.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding the behaviour of inject used with a lambda in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102165/understanding-the-behaviour-of-inject-used-with-a-lambda-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out the related question! My googling and the site-search mechanism didn't point me there before. It helped me see I'd just made a dumb syntax error earlier (I tried a call of `(1..5).inject([]) proc`) that made me misunderstand what I was seeing. So what I needed was in fact:

```
def wrapper proc
  (1..5).inject 0, proc
end
```

Comment: Did you test it? When I try your `wrapper` by calling `wrapper &proc` as you specified in your question, it gives me an error.

Comment: So I also changed the call to be just wrapper proc, and that works fine. The next step I've come to which has also stumped me is this: `summer = Proc.new {|sum, n| sum + n}`; `rap = Proc.new {|proc| (1..5).inject 0, proc}` ; `curried = rap.curry` ; `curried[summer]` results in: `TypeError: #<Proc:0x00000103132cd0@(pry):1> is not a symbol`. :c

Comment: Another stupid mistake! I needed this: `rap = Proc.new {|proc| (1..5).inject 0, &proc}` and now, voila, it works.

Comment: This is where I ended up, Boris: https://github.com/mooreniemi/experiments/blob/master/curried_summer.rb

Comment: Hm, and when defining a Proc, you can just say `proc { |a, b| a + b }` instead of `Proc.new { |a, b| a + b }`.

Answer (score 8):

The way to do it is

```
def wrapper &block
  ( 1..5 ).reduce &block
end

p = proc { |a, b| a + b }

wrapper &p
#=> 15
```

But in your question, you interestingly attempted to use `yield`. When you use `yield`, you don't need to explicitly mention the `&block` parameter – a method cannot refuse a block, which is always callable by `yield` inside the method. However, `yield` expects arguments. The way to use `yield` to achieve your goal is:

```
def wrapper_2
  ( 1..5 ).reduce { |accumulator, input| yield accumulator, input }
end
```

This formulation is still a bit awkward. It turns out that there is a secret way to obtain the block inside a method even if you do not specify the `&block` parameter, and that is by using unadorned `Proc.new` inside the method:

```
def wrapper_3
  ( 1..5 ).reduce &Proc.new
end
```